# How do i attached a tap event to a uiwebview?

Tags: iphone

I am trying to attach a UITapGestureRecognizer to a webview that i am creating and then remove that view when a user taps the webview. Below is my sample code. What am i doing wrong? Thanks!

```
- (void) setupPuzzle1
{
puzzleDuration--;
//Create object circle
UIImageView *circleView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"red-circle.png"] highlightedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"red-circle.png"]];

UITapGestureRecognizer *recognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(removeImage:)];
recognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
recognizer.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
recognizer.delegate = self;

[circleView addGestureRecognizer:recognizer];

[recognizer release];

int x = rand()%280;
int y = rand()%420;

circleView.frame = CGRectMake(x,y,40,40);
[self.view addSubview:circleView];

if (puzzleDuration > 0)
{
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(setupPuzzle1) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
}

}



#pragma mark - UITapGestureRecognizer methods


- (void)removeImage:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{
NSLog(@"Remove Image");
[[recognizer view] removeFromSuperview];
}
```

@end

Comment: To start, please tell us what does and doesn't work with this code.

Comment: Your question doesn't match your code -- do you intend to add the recognizer to a web view or to an image view (which is what your code does now)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you weren't talking about `UIWebView` at all. If you did, your code didn't reflect that. As such you are dealing with `UIImageView` and the reason is pretty straightforward as any `UIImageView` object by default has its `userInteractionEnabled` set to `NO`. You should change it to `YES`. So add this line,

```
circleView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
```

and you aren't releasing it either. So add

```
[circleView release];
```

after you add it as a subview.